# iPhone SDK: Navigation among view controllers causes crash

Tags: iphone

(Sorry, I restarted this thread as I incorrectly accepted the answer for my problem.)

My app is crashing when I navigate two view controllers in my application. For example, if I do this sequence:

RootController ViewControllerA
ViewControllerB ViewControllerA

My app crashes.

It crashes when I pressed the back button in ViewControllerB. So, It seems like it is with two or more ViewControllers being pushed. Each by themselves work.

I don't know why.

I don't see any output to the console. Is there some type of debugging I should put?

I looked at the dealloc() to make sure all properties were being release before dealloc()

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is your 2nd view controller holding a reference to the 1st without retaining it? If so, when your 2nd is dealloc'd it could release the 1st and cause it to have no references and be an invalid object.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by holding a reference to the 1st without retaining it? Do you have an example?

Comment: In ViewControllerB if you have a pointer to ViewControllerA *viewControllerA and you don't call [viewControllerA retain] but in the dealloc method you do call [viewControllerA release] that will lower the retainCount and possibly make viewControllerA an invalid object. Does that make sense?